# Sql Query Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I need to query a taken room which is present in all the dates from the table.

My table data is

```
-----------------------------------
|Room No | Date         |  Type   |
-----------------------------------
|1       | 1 JAN 2016   | AC      |
|2       | 1 JAN 2016   | AC      |
|3       | 1 JAN 2016   | Non AC  |
|1       | 2 JAN 2016   | AC      |
|3       | 2 JAN 2016   | AC      |
|1       | 3 JAN 2016   | AC      |
|2       | 3 JAN 2016   | AC      |
|3       | 3 JAN 2016   | Non AC  |
```

Now I want the result Like

```
------------------------
| RoomNo    |  Type    |
------------------------
| 1         |   AC     |
| 3         |  NON AC  |
```

See the above example room no 2 is not present on  2nd jan so it's not required.

Comment: School assignment? What have you tried? (Perhaps a `GROUP BY`?)

Comment: Use `GROUP BY Type` no?

Comment: What Group By it will not check all the date present

Comment: No I Clearly returned i want what are the rooms present in all the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this problem is to compare the number of unique dates a room has to the total number of unique dates:

```
SELECT   room_no, type
FROM     (SELECT   room_no, type, COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS cnt
          FROM     rooms
          GROUP BY room_no, type) r
JOIN     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS cnt
          FROM   rooms) c ON r.cnt = c.cnt
```

Comment: I can got answer from your query but please can you explain it i cannot able to understand

Comment: The first query (aliased as `r`) returns the distinct number of dates per room. The second query (aliased as `c`) returns the total distinct number of dates in the table. If they are equal (the join condition), it means the room is occupied in each day that's represented in the table.

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways,as it represent islands and gaps problem,assuming you have three rooms,you just want to give some value if there is gap

```
select row_number() ovver (partition by date order by roomno) as rn,
roomno,type
from 
yourtable
```

now you can select all the rooms which are booked each day using

```
  with cte
    as
    (
     select row_number() ovver (partition by date order by roomno) as rn,
        roomno,type
        from 
        yourtable
    )
select * from cte where rn=3
```

not booked rooms using

```
     with cte
        as
        (
         select row_number() ovver (partition by date order by roomno) as rn,
            roomno,type
            from 
            yourtable
        )


  select * from cte where rn<3
```

Comment: is this query only work when there are 3 dates? how if there are more than 3 dates? for example the date is 1,2,3,4,5 Jan 2016?

Comment: NO i just give an example actuall i will get upto 60 or 90 dates also

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
My Sql Server Version:Microsoft SQL Server 2012 
The code below can run at above 2005
*/
--Step1:Initialize DataTable
select * from (VALUES(1,cast('1 JAN 2016' as Date),'AC')
                    ,(2,cast('1 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC')
                    ,(3,cast('1 JAN 2016'as Date),'Non AC')
                    ,(1,cast('2 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC')
                    ,(3,cast('2 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC')
                    ,(1,cast('3 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC')
                    ,(2,cast('3 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC' )
                    ,(3,cast('3 JAN 2016'as Date),'Non AC' )
                      ) as a(RoomNo,Date,Type)
-- result
/*
RoomNo      Date       Type
----------- ---------- ------
1           1 JAN 2016 AC
2           1 JAN 2016 AC
3           1 JAN 2016 Non AC
1           2 JAN 2016 AC
3           2 JAN 2016 AC
1           3 JAN 2016 AC
2           3 JAN 2016 AC
3           3 JAN 2016 Non AC

(8 row(s) affected)

*/
--Step2: The Result
--Solution A:
;with FilterResult as (
select RoomNo,Type,Row_Number() over(partition by RoomNo order by Date) as rn
from (VALUES(1,cast('1 JAN 2016' as Date),'AC')
                    ,(2,cast('1 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC')
                    ,(3,cast('1 JAN 2016'as Date),'Non AC')
                    ,(1,cast('2 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC')
                    ,(3,cast('2 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC')
                    ,(1,cast('3 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC')
                    ,(2,cast('3 JAN 2016'as Date),'AC' )
                    ,(3,cast('3 JAN 2016'as Date),'Non AC' )
                      ) as a(RoomNo,Date,Type)
)
select RoomNo,Type 
from FilterResult
where rn = 3  
--result 
/*
RoomNo      Type
----------- ------
1           AC
3           Non AC

(2 row(s) affected)
*/                    
--Solution B:
;with SourceTable as(
 select * from (VALUES(1,'1 JAN 2016','AC')
                    ,(2,'1 JAN 2016','AC')
                    ,(3,'1 JAN 2016','Non AC')
                    ,(1,'2 JAN 2016','AC')
                    ,(3,'2 JAN 2016','AC')
                    ,(1,'3 JAN 2016','AC')
                    ,(2,'3 JAN 2016','AC' )
                    ,(3,'3 JAN 2016','Non AC' )
                      ) as a(RoomNo,Date,Type)
),
FilterResult as (
select RoomNo,max(Date) as Date from SourceTable
group by RoomNo
having count(Date) =3
)
select a.RoomNo,b.Type
from FilterResult as a inner join SourceTable as b on a.RoomNo = b.RoomNo and a.Date = b.Date
--Result
/*
RoomNo      Type
----------- ------
1           AC
3           Non AC

(2 row(s) affected)
*/
```